# How to use api response data in any other function besides view?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have used react-native fetch to get data from REST API. its displaying fine in view. Now I need to use response onPress function of a button.
for Response

```
.then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({
      data: responseJson,
    })
  })
```

I get value as

```
{
"id": 2,
"foo": "bar"
}
```

Its working fine in View with

```
<Text>{this.state.data.answer}</Text>
```

I need this with

```
_onPressButtonA() {
    alert("bar");
  }
```

My Button Code is

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButtonA}>
  <Text>{this.state.data.option1}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**Full Code**

```
class QuestionScreen extends React.Component {
state = {
data: '',
}
componentDidMount() {
return fetch('http://example.com/api', {
method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    param: 'foo',
  }),
}).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
      data: responseJson,
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
_onPressButtonA() {
//Needed to be displayed here
}
render() {
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20 }}>

    <View style={{ margin: 15 }}>

      <View style={{ margin: 5 }} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButtonA}>
        <Text>{this.state.data.answer}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your full code if possible.

Comment: I guess you can access this.state.data.answer in your _onPressButtonA as well. or did you try and had a problem?

Comment: @ducmai I tried that. It says undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.data')

Comment: you should declare your _onPressButtonA like this _onPressButtonA = () => {}

Comment: where is 'answer'  in your response?

Comment: @ducmai thanks. It just helped me out.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my comment you should use arrow function so you can access state via this

```
_onPressButtonA = () => {
//Needed to be displayed here
}
```

or you can bind this manually in constructor

```
this._onPressButtonA = this._onPressButtonA.bind(this)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. It just helped me out :)